# "The installation failed. The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install."

Tags: macos, plugins, code-signing

I'm getting this error on my mid '11 Mac Mini (running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6) when I'm trying to install an audio plug-in by Presonus, the demo of OrangeVocoder 10th Anniversary Edition. The software manufacturer is in Germany and this is just the demo, so I doubt they will be much help. The first thing I tried was downloading a new copy of the DMG file, but it gave the same error when I attempted to install.

I believe the problem is because I had this installed previously, but I recently uninstalled it. After reading [this Apple thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7270807?start=0&tstart=0) I opened the .MPK file (Show Contents) and copied the contents to the desktop and tried to install from there, but got the same error. I also used Terminal and navigated to /private/var/db/receipts and deleted two .plist files that referenced the software. Lastly, I tried this command to disable code-signing check, but it didn't help either: `defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify -bool true`

Worth noting that the DMG is not signed (I checked with terminal command `codesign -dv path\ to\ DMG`) but the DMG does indeed pass image verification in Disk Utility.

At this point I am out of ideas, but I really need this plug-in for a project I'm working on. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide the download link?

Comment: Thanks, FrontENG. I'm using the older version because that's what all my patches are written for but this is the current one: http://www.zynaptiq.com/orangevocoder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! I was able to install the program by using this shareware: [CharlesSoft Pacifist.](https://www.charlessoft.com/)